# ASP.NET MVC5 JQuery Datatables CSS not working with Bootstrap Lumen

Tags: css, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I'm not able to get the right styling for my datatables.
[This is how my datatables look right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGXxT.png)

This is my BundleConfig.cs file:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/scripts/bootbox.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen.css",
                  "~/Content/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"
            ));
    }
```

and this is what I'm rendering in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

[It works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg8Du.png) if I remove the Lumen css file from my BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"
            ));
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.0, JQuery 1.10.2 and datatables 1.10.11. I know these versions are old but i'm learning MVC from Mosh Hamedani's course and he's using these versions so I'm just trying to follow him atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is in the Lumen theme. I changed to various other themes to check if they have the same problem and it's only Lumen. Datatables are working fine in all other themes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with the lumen theme. Instead of using the local or downloaded files. I used the cdn links of jquery.datatables and it worked for me.
Use this in your layout file :-

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>`